# uri redirect with domain change

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I'm not the best at this but I have to do a redirect

```
domain1.tld/subfolder/seo/based/uri
```

and i need to redirect to

```
subd.domain2.tld/seo/based/uri
```

is that possible?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, these all dynamic requests. Like:

```
domain1.tld/forums/forum/2-network-announcements/topic-name-with-id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in .htaccess or PHP, but I find it's easier in PHP.

To do it this way, the PHP file for the first URL should contain:

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://subd.domain2.tld/seo/based/uri");
?>
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting from .htaccess is immediate. Meaning, if you redirect from .htaccess, no code will be run at domain1.tld/subfolder/seo/based/uri. If that's what you want, then add these lines to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain1.tld/subfolder/(.*)$ subd.domain2.tld/$1
```

If you do want to run some code on domain1.tld/subfolder/seo/based/uri, then go read @tomtheman5's answer, because that will be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file or the vhost for domain1.tld, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(.*) http://subd.domain2.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You could also use mod_alias if the 2 hosts have different document roots:

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://subd.domain2.tld
```